# Empty rule and pattern matching in Makefile

Tags: makefile

While building `Makefile` with some pattern `%` rule, I've discovered unexpected, yet desirable behavior. However, I don't understand why it works, how it works, and can't find anything about it in manual.

```
print-a:
print-b:
print-c:
print-%:
    @echo $*
```

Which results in:

```
% make print-a
a
% make print-b
b
% make print-c
c
% make print-d
d
```

How Makefile treats `print-a` `print-b` `print-c` targets? Is it some kind of alias or fallthrough? Is this reliable?

Another question is how to limit pattern rule to only `a` `b` `c` but not `d`?

This seems very convenient as this way bash auto-completion works out of the box for the pattern rule.

Answer (score 2):

It is your pattern rule that catches them all. The empty rules have no effect at all (they would cancel implicit rules if there were implicit rules for `print-%` and if they had the same prerequisites but as it is not the case...)

When you know the list of targets to cover, to limit the scope of pattern rules, you can simply turn them into [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
print-a print-b print-c: print-%:
    @echo $*
```

or:

```
$(addprefix print-,a b c): print-%:
    @echo $*
```

Demo:

```
$ make -j1 print-a print-b print-c print-d
a
b
c
make: *** No rule to make target 'print-d'.  Stop.
```

If what you know is not the list of targets to cover but the list of targets **not** to cover you can add more specific rules<sup>1</sup> for them, as they take precedence over less specific ones:

```
$ cat Makefile
print-%:
    @echo generic $@

print-foo%:
    @echo intermediate $@

print-a:
    @echo specific $@

$ make -j1 print-a print-foob print-c
specific print-a
intermediate print-foob
generic print-c
```

---

<sup>1</sup> More specific means either a non-pattern rule or another pattern rule with a shorter stem (the stem is the part of the target name that matches the `%` wildcard character).

Answer (score 0):

A target without rules simply adds dependencies (none, in these cases).
To make the specific targets do nothing, we need to add at least one command.

E.g.

```
print-a print-b print-c:
    @true

print-%:
    @echo $*
```

Comment: Oh! True, I've used that before to add dependencies or variables to target - the only difference, is that here they are empty. I'm really happy how it works now, as the main reason I did it was to have auto-completion.